# R crash when I get to a certian variable length

Tags: r

I have several columns with large amounts of data, I can see all the data in the global environment in RStudio but once it get to "write.xport" to export it to a xpt file it crashes.

The amount of data in each of the two columns are 2600 characters, if it's 1600 char it works, is  there a limit that is not documented?

**SCRIPT**

```
library(Hmisc)
library(RODBC)
library(SASxport)
library(haven)

Driver = paste("driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}",
"server=system \MS_SQLEXPRESS",
"database=CheckData",
"UID=peas",
"PWD=corn",
sep=";")

conn<- odbcDriverConnect(Driver)

data <- sqlQuery(conn, paste("exec [dbo].[sp_Rtest]"))

write.xport(data, file=paste("C:\XPT\DmExtract.xpt"), verbose=TRUE,
sasVer="9.00",

         cDate=Sys.time(),
        Mformats=NULL,
        autogen.formats=FALSE)
```

**My Table**

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Rtest](
[cola] [nvarchar] (4000) NULL,
[colb] [nvarchar] (4000) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

**My Stored Proc**

```
/****** Object: StoredProcedure [dbo].[sp_Rtest] Script Date: 10/15/2021 5:28:33 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author: <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Rtest]

AS
BEGIN
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT CAST(cola AS nvarchar(4000)) as cola ,CAST(colb AS nvarchar(4000)) as colb FROM Rtest
END
```

Comment: If you try the script in R outside of RStudio, does it still crash?

Comment: Yes it does, I can run it in SQL same result? I get a "invalid BXL stream", I don't get this error in Rstudio however is just crashes. But the error yields no fix when I search for resolution